# Astro-Sanity Integration - Error when evaluating SSR module

Tags: backend, server-side-rendering, sanity, astrojs

I'm trying to integrate Sanity (v3) with Astro (v3.5.5) with the official ([Sanity integration for Astro](https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity-astro)). I've thoroughly gone through all the documentation, but when I want to npm run dev Astro I'm hit with these errors:

" Error when evaluating SSR module /Users/Documents/project/astro/astro.config.mjs: failed to import "@sanity/astro" "
" Unable to load your Astro config
error   **vite_ssr_import_1**.default is not a function"

I've tried restarting from scratch a couple of times but I'm always hit with the same issue. Astro launches if I comment the Sanity integration within astro.confing.mjs, so the problem is definitely somewhere there...

Here is my configuration:

astro.config.mjs

```
import sanity from "@sanity/astro";
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";

export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [
    sanity({
      projectId: 'vmv3i2a5',
      dataset: 'production',
      apiVersion: '2023-02-08',
      useCdn: false,
    }),
  ],
});
```

sanity.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "sanity"
import { deskTool } from "sanity/desk"
import { visionTool } from "@sanity/vision"
import { schemaTypes } from "./schemas"
import { deskStructure } from "./deskStructure"

export default defineConfig({
  name: 'default',
  title: 'Project',
  projectId: 'vmv3i2a5',
  dataset: 'production',

  plugins: [
    deskTool({
      structure: deskStructure
    }),
    visionTool(),
  ],

  schema: {
    types: schemaTypes,
  },
})
```

sanity.cli.js

```
import {defineCliConfig} from 'sanity/cli'

export default defineCliConfig({
  api: {
    projectId: 'vmv3i2a5',
    dataset: 'production'
  }
})
```

env.d.ts

```
/// <reference types="astro/client" />
/// <reference types="@sanity/astro/module" />
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this yesterday, when I found this:
https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity-astro/issues/92
Downgrading to @sanity/astro@1.3.0 worked for me.

Comment: `@sanity/astro` v2.1.1 is also working.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the named export?

```
import { sanityIntegration } from '@sanity/astro';
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [
    sanityIntegration({
      projectId: "<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>",
      dataset: "<YOUR-DATASET-NAME>",
      // Set useCdn to false if you're building statically.
      useCdn: false,
    }),
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I found the answer to this when I ran in to it myself, change sanity() to sanityIntegration() in your astro config and it will work, no idea why astro add command adds the wrong integration name but it does